# How variables of config file are getting replaced by docker-compose ENV?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, divolte

Reading [this repository](https://github.com/divolte/docker-divolte) I cannot understand how the variables of [divolte-collector.conf](https://github.com/divolte/docker-divolte/blob/master/conf/divolte-collector.conf) inside ${?*} are getting replaced by the ENV of docker-compose. I have been reading all repository and searching in docker documentation, but whithout finding any clue.

[Dockerfile](https://github.com/divolte/docker-divolte/blob/master/Dockerfile)

[docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/divolte/docker-divolte/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

Comment: The [divolte-collector.conf](http://divolte-releases.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/divolte-collector/0.9.0/userdoc/html/configuration.html#divolte-collector-conf) file supports environment variable overrides using the `${?VAR_NAME}` syntax. Compose sets the variables for the container via the `environment` collection in the `docker-compose.yml` file. See also https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Answer (score 0):

Phil was kind enough to correctly answer this question.
(Post an "answer" and I will happily delete this copy.)

> The [divolte-collector.conf](http://divolte-releases.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/divolte-collector/0.9.0/userdoc/html/configuration.html#divolte-collector-conf) file supports environment variable overrides using the ${?VAR_NAME} syntax. Compose sets the variables for the container via the environment collection in the docker-compose.yml file. See also https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables